# .findQuery().get('length') giving result as 0 every time

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using .findQuery().get('length') to get total count of records available in model for specific filtration.

But every time it is showing result as 0.

I have listed my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/2/).

```
    total:function(){ 
        return App.Person.query({ contacttype: 1 }).get('length'); 
    }.property('@each.isLoaded')
```

I have tried same thing using .find but still it is showing same result :
Pls check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/8/)

How to calculate length of records based of filtration criteria?
Pls check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/10/)
Here i am trying to calculate length of contact type.
Can anyone tell me how to calculate it?

Now,i have updated my last fiddle to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/12/).
How to calculate total no of records if my model records are changing based on filtration.

Pls refer to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/12/) (Click on type1 and type2 to filtrate data).
Here i am not able to calculate total records based on filtration condition.

Comment: Simple google search might help.  http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-models/

Comment: no,it is not working refer :(http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/3/)

Comment: what do you mean? you have 3 fixtures in your example, 2 of them have the contacttype set to `1` which is the property you are filtering in your routes model hook, so your controller content will only contain the records which meet this filter criteria, makes sense?

Comment: yes,i want to list total length of records which have contact type as 1 and total length of records which have contact type as 2.

Comment: edited my answer with working jsfiddle, is this what your where after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already are fetching the records in your `IndexRoute` model hook, which will set the controller's `content` property when it returns the records, therefore you should in your controller access the controller's `content` property instead and also watch it for changes:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  total: function() { 
    return this.get('content.length'); 
  }.property('content.length')
});
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/9/) your working jsfiddle.

### Edit

If you want to filter for `contacttype` in your controller you should not already filter in the routes model hook, but instead return there all records you have:

```
...
model: function() {
  return App.Person.find();
}
...
```

And then filter in your controller instead:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  total: function() { 
    return this.get('content.length'); 
  }.property('content.length'),

  totalContactType1: function() {
    return this.get('content').filterProperty('contacttype', 1).get('length');
  }.property('content.@each.contacttype'),

  totalContactType2: function() {
    return this.get('content').filterProperty('contacttype', 2).get('length');
  }.property('content.@each.contacttype')
});
```

[Here another jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/11/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: @user2625690, have you seen the updated fiddle? it's showing the length at the bottom.

Comment: ,I have seen it but i have one more doubt which i have listed in updated question.I want to calculate length of contact type pls refer http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/10/.

Comment: How to calculate length of records based of filtration criteria? Pls check this http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/10/.

Comment: :Pls refer to http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/12/ (Click on type1 and type2 to filtrate data). Here i am not able to calculate total records based on filtration condition.